# Using keySet() method then changing the Set to a String Array? Java

Tags: java, set, treemap, arrays

So this should be really simple since I know it's possible (I just don't understand 'Set' very much).

So basically there is this TreeMap, let's call it aTree. So I need to do something like:

```
somethingHereProbably = aTree.keySet();
somethingHereProbably.toStringArray();
```

Comment: Specifying which language/platform you're talking about in the tags would make this question easier to find.

Answer (score 62):

You can do

```
Map<String, Object> map = ...
String[] strings = map.keySet().toArray(new String[map.size()]);
```

This works for any kind of map, including TreeMap